# Why does IE 11 report "Invalid argument" for chained selectors :tabbable:first?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-11

I'm tracing through jQuery now, and I'm posting this in hopes that someone might have come across this before. I'm working with jQuery 3.2.1 that has been extended by a snippet from jQuery UI so that jQuery can use a pseudo-selector :tabbable. That said, the code I'm working with tries :tabbable:first. The :tabbable seems to be working fine, but only in IE jQuery reports "Invalid argument" seemingly when the :first test begins. Has anyone experienced issues with jQuery chained pseudo-selectors in IE 11? Code works fine in Chrome and FF.

Comment: it works on IE 11.31617763.0 + win10

Comment: Thanks gaetano, unfortunately I need to get it working Win7pro + IE <11.3

Comment: you may try: $('[tabindex]:first') or $(':tabbable').eq(0)?

Comment: I tried these and some other permutations, none worked with the other code I'm working with. At this point I'll punt and not select on tabindex, I'll just select on known structure .find('>a:nth-of-type(1)'). Still, I'm curious why :tabbable:first didn't work in IE <11.3 ... but curiosity killed the cat

Comment: Can you please check whether any new update for Windows 7 or any update for IE 11 is available and if any available than can you please try to install it to check whether solves this issue or not? Let us know your testing results. We will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Hi Deepak, that would be an "ask" of our organization software admins. Doable, however if our org is still on <11.3 likely others are also. For now I'll use other selectors (a solution I can directly control).